# Nested for loop issue will not move to next file

Tags: bash, bash-completion

```
find_date=$(stat -c %y $files | awk '{print $1}')
#Grabbing each file from the array
for file in "${files[@]}"; do
# We get the date part
file_date=''

#Reading the date and breaking by the - mark
IFS="-" read -ra parts <<< "$file"


unset file_date
find_date=$(stat -c %y $files | awk '{print $1}')
echo "File Date: " $find_date



for t in "${find_date[@]}"; do
#Putting the date into the array
if [[ $t == [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9] ]]; then
    file_date=$t
    break
fi
done
echo "T: " $t
```

So everything works but the for loop where it should move to the next file. When i run my script i notice all the errors for the STAT command not working because after it does the first file it is still trying to STAT that file and not the next one in the list

Comment: When posting a question, post a *minimal* example that demonstrates your error, not your entire script.

Comment: there you go I post the whole thing so they can see it

Comment: Thank you. If there is code that you can omit without eliminating your error, it makes the question much easier to read and answer.

Comment: thats all I can narrow down .. I can not get that to move to the next file. I put all the files=(*.wav) then it hits here with the first file works fine then it just does not wanna move to the next file

Comment: Sorry, your edits are fine. I should have made that clearer.

Comment: do you know what is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
find_date=$(stat -c %y $files | awk '{print $1}')
```

`files` is the array, so `$files` expands to the first element of that array each time through the loop. You want to use the `file` variable that you use to iterate over the array.

```
for file in "${files[@]}"; do
    ...
    find_date=$(stat -c %y "$file" | awk '{print $1}')
    #                      ^^^^^^^
    ...
done
```

Comment: I feel like an idiot I mean this is my 1st script but wow just I never looked at my stat command the close I just kinda went into the for loop right away ...... I mean I wrote java and c but thank you so much!

Comment: Yeah, it's a little annoying that `$files` and `${files[0]}` are essentially the same. I'm not sure if that's a conscious design decision, or a side effect of how arrays are implemented, but it can definitely bite you if you aren't careful :)

Answer (score 1):

reset the file_date so it does not 'remember' the result of the previous loop, ie:

```
unset file_date
for t in "${find_date[@]}"; do
   #Putting the date into the array
    if [[ $t == [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9] ]]; then
        file_date=$t
        break
    fi
done
```

Comment: Then would it do the stat command again? if so where? I am confused why would I unset it right before I use it for the array?

Comment: okay the above is a fix to a certain bug,  but not it seems the bug you're looking for.  The stat command is outside ALL the loops as is the setting of file_date, ie that is fixed for the whole run

Comment: So you think that will fix the issue? I mean i am coping some files now to test it now I was just wondering

Comment: It really depend what you are trying to do

Comment: Basically you set find_Date once, empty it after the first run, it stays empty.  For file_date and file_year etc you never reset them so it will use the last value IF you don't enter the 'setting' code.

Comment: Ill put all the echo statement in a log.log file but I do not know to so post an attachment here

Comment: It worked for the first one but the other 2 files didnt move at all

Comment: What it is doing now is that it is not moving to the next file. if we can get it to move to next file it would work...